# MsalUiRequiredException: No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, graphserviceclient

I am developing Windows form application using Graph API. I created a function that returns a GraphServiceClient and a function that returns signed-in user. When I launch the application, an error appears- MsalUiRequiredException: No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call. Here is the code:

```
 public class GraphHelper
{
    private static string ClientId = "clientID";
    private static string Tenant = "tenantID";
    public static IPublicClientApplication PublicClientApp;
    private static string[] scopes = { "user.read" };
    private static GraphServiceClient graphClient;

    public static async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
    {
        PublicClientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
            .WithRedirectUri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient")
            .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, Tenant)
            .Build();

        IEnumerable<IAccount> accounts = await PublicClientApp.GetAccountsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        IAccount firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();
        var authResult = await PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, firstAccount)
                                              .ExecuteAsync();

        authResult = await PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                                  .ExecuteAsync();

        return authResult.AccessToken;
    }

    public static async Task<GraphServiceClient> GetGraphServiceClient()
    {
        var delegateAuthProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
        {
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", GetAccessToken().Result);

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        });
        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(delegateAuthProvider);

        return graphClient;
    }

    public  async Task<User> GetMeAsync()
    {
        graphClient = GetGraphServiceClient().Result;

        var user = await graphClient.Me
            .Request()
            .GetAsync();

        return user;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`GetAccountsAsync` returns all the available accounts in the user token cache for the application. When you call `GetAccountsAsync` for the first time or if you the token cache is empty it can return empty accounts collection. In that case `AcquireTokenSilent` will throw the exception. Add try catch block around `AcquireTokenSilent` and if an expcetion is raised then call `AcquireTokenInteractive`.

```
AuthenticationResult authResult;
try
{
    authResult = await PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, firstAccount)
                                          .ExecuteAsync();
}
catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
{
    authResult = await PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                              .ExecuteAsync();
}
```